# Get current month by .getMonth() method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have pasted the code. I am trying to show the current month by the getMonth method. I know it shows a month(0= Jan to 11= Dec). That's why its showing September in my case. I tried adding 1 (.getMonth()+1) but it didn't work

```
$scope.fftReadingsFor = fftChartTitle+ fftSelectedPointDate.getMonth() +"/"+fftSelectedPointDate.getDate()+"/"+fftSelectedPointDate.getFullYear()+" "+ $scope.fftReadings.selectedTime;
```

Comment: What output it is displaying ??

Comment: its showing 9/3/2017. when I added 1 (.getMonth()+1). it shows 91/3/2017

Comment: Your output is of string type.

Comment: yeah what should I do in that case?

Comment: Simly use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/): `moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i am getting

```
var currentDate = new Date();

var currentDateString = (a.getMonth()+1)+ '/'+ a.getDate() + '/'+ a.getFullYear();
```

**Output**

`10/3/2017`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add parenthesis and it showed me string

Answer (score 0):

```
 var date=new Date("9/3/2017");
 var nextMonthDate=new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1));
 console.log("Original Date:"+date);
 console.log("Next Month Date:"+nextMonthDate);
 var dateString= (nextMonthDate.getMonth()+1)+ '/'+ nextMonthDate.getDate() + '/'+ nextMonthDate.getFullYear();
 console.log("Next Month Date in String:"+dateString);
```